# R plot with tilted bars

Tags: r, plot

I have been trying to make a plot for a publication but somehow some of the bars are broken or tilted to the right. I have been looking where is the problem but so luck yet. Where would be the problem: the data, the library that I am using or something with my OS? Here some details about my system and R version, the code I am running and the data:

My system and R:

```
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin15.6.0                
system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          5.3                         
year           2019                        
month          03                          
day            11                          
svn rev        76217                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
nickname       Great Truth
```

The code:

```
library(Sushi)

pop1<-read.table ("pop1.stack.csv", header=TRUE, ",")
pop2<-read.table ("pop2.stack.csv", header=TRUE, ",")
fst1x2<-read.table ("fst.stack.csv", header=TRUE, ",")

head(pop1)
head(pop2)
head(fst1x2)


par(mfrow=c(3,1),mar=c(2,5,2,2))

chrom="Scaffold_2074"
chromstart=10000
chromend=7730000


plotBedgraph(pop1,chrom,chromstart,chromend,
             color=SushiColors(3)(6)[2])
axis(side=2,las=2,tcl=.2)
mtext("Pop1" ~(pi),side=2,line=2.5,cex=1.5,font=2)

plotBedgraph(pop2, chrom, chromstart, chromend,
             flip=TRUE, color=SushiColors(3)(6)[6], ymax=1.4)
labelgenome(chrom,chromstart,chromend,side=3,n=4,scale="Mb",line=0.02)

axis(side=2,las=2,tcl=.2,at=pretty(par("yaxp")[c(1,2)]),
     labels=-1*pretty(par("yaxp")[c(1,2)]))
mtext("Pop2" ~(pi),side=2,line=2.5,cex=1.5,font=2)


plotBedgraph(fst1x2,chrom,chromstart,chromend,
             color=SushiColors(3)(6)[4])
axis(side=2,las=2,tcl=.2)
mtext(expression(italic(F)[st]),side=2,line=2.5,cex=1.5,font=2)
labelgenome(chrom,chromstart=chromstart,chromend=chromend,n=4,chromline=2,
            scale="Mb")


dev.print(png, file = "stack.fig.png", width = 300, height = 200, units='mm', res = 300)
```

The plot I get:

[image: Tilted bars]

You can find the data on the link.[Data](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1j5koeu5uayl0ke/AAChEFhAwkVZYxn5jIRzG6PKa?dl=0)

The data looks like this:

```
> head(pop1)
            chr start    end         pi
1 Scaffold_2074 10000  60000 0.02540892
2 Scaffold_2074 20000  70000 0.03581412
3 Scaffold_2074 30000  80000 0.03999322
4 Scaffold_2074 40000  90000 0.05402227
5 Scaffold_2074 50000 100000 0.05350814
6 Scaffold_2074 60000 110000 0.04260332


 > head(pop2)
            Chr start    end         pi
1 Scaffold_2074 10000  60000 0.01910726
2 Scaffold_2074 20000  70000 0.02757993
3 Scaffold_2074 30000  80000 0.03359872
4 Scaffold_2074 40000  90000 0.04590020
5 Scaffold_2074 50000 100000 0.04594944
6 Scaffold_2074 60000 110000 0.04054279


> head(fst1x2)
            chr start    end    Fst01
1 Scaffold_2074 10000  60000 0.101773
2 Scaffold_2074 20000  70000 0.096691
3 Scaffold_2074 30000  80000 0.099691
4 Scaffold_2074 40000  90000 0.085867
5 Scaffold_2074 50000 100000 0.079663
6 Scaffold_2074 60000 110000 0.065473
```

Any suggest will be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Contact the maintainer for package `Sushi`. These all involve `plotBedraph()` which is presumably a function in that package, `maintainer(Sushi)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I download your dataset and install `Sushi` package and I get the same issue than you with "tilted" bars.

After comparing your dataset with the bedgraph dataset provided as example of the `Sushi` packages, I constated that you have an overlap in your rows. 
I provided you an example here in order to see the structure:

```r
> head(Sushi_DNaseI.bedgraph)
  chrom   start     end value
1 chr11 1640504 1640664     1
2 chr11 1640904 1641004     1
3 chr11 1641004 1641064     2
4 chr11 1641064 1641164     1
5 chr11 1645224 1645384     1
6 chr11 1645504 1645664     1
```

As you can see, the end of each row is not overlapping the start of the following rows. If you are doing a zoom of your plot bedgraph, you can see that this overlap is creating issue in the plotting:
[image]

So, I think a way to solve this issue is to modify the `end` of your dataset. I don't know if it makes sense for your research and the result you are trying to plot. So, you can use `dplyr` to replace the `end` of each row by the `start` of the following row.

```r
library(tidyverse)
p1bis <- pop1[1:30,] %>% mutate(end = lead(start,1)) %>% filter(!is.na(end))

> head(p1bis)
            chr start   end         pi
1 Scaffold_2074 10000 20000 0.02540892
2 Scaffold_2074 20000 30000 0.03581412
3 Scaffold_2074 30000 40000 0.03999322
4 Scaffold_2074 40000 50000 0.05402227
5 Scaffold_2074 50000 60000 0.05350814
6 Scaffold_2074 60000 70000 0.04260332
```

And if you are plotting this new dataset `p1bis`

```r
chrom="Scaffold_2074"
chromstart=10000
chromend=300000
plotBedgraph(p1bis,chrom,chromstart,chromend,
             color=SushiColors(3)(6)[2])
axis(side=2,las=2,tcl=.2)
axis(side=1,las=2,tcl=.2)
mtext("Pop1" ~(pi),side=2,line=2.5,cex=1.5,font=2)
```

[image]

So, now, if you are applying that to your three datasets:

```r
pop1 <- pop1 %>% mutate(end = lead(start,1)) %>% filter(!is.na(end))
pop2 <- pop2 %>% mutate(end = lead(start,1)) %>% filter(!is.na(end))
fst <- fst %>% mutate(end = lead(start,1)) %>% filter(!is.na(end))
```

and you are plotting them using the same code that you provided:
[image]

I hope it helps you to understand the issue with your plot. 
Let me know if you need some precisions.

Comment: Thank you so much. It makes sense. This package was developed to plot read coverage across the genome and not nucleotide diversity or genetic differentiation as I am doing. I also tried to keep only non overlapping window filtering them out with awk: 
cat pop1.stack.csv | awk 'NR % 6 == 0' > pop1.nonoverlapping.csv and it works as well. However I like the way you did since it has higher resolution of the peaks.

Comment: Glad that it helps you to figure out the issue. Regarding `awk` I can't be of any help. I don't know much about this. but I hope you will figure it out how to get your plot done.

Comment: Yes. I got it done using your method. The awk was just another way but not as good as yours. Thank you :P